# Install gem for all installed ruby versions?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a setup script that downloads the files for a number of rails apps.  For various reasons, the apps are on different versions and it needs to remain that way.

It is possible to search the .ruby-versions files to determine all the required ruby versions and then iterate through them and run rbenv install  on each. Is there a quick way to run `gem install bundler` for every ruby version without changing the local version and doing it manually?

Comment: I assume you are using RVM, if so then just have a file called you could do something like the following on bash console:                  
`versions=(YOUR_VERSIONS_HERE_AS ARRAY)
for var in "${versions[@]}"
do
  rvm gem install GEM_NAME
done`

Comment: sorry forgot to include `rvm use var` in the do block